# Abnormal CSS3 Animation Behaviour

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to learn CSS3 by making a simple image slider using animations.
I have successfully achieved the animation pattern to my needs by doing some calculation but the problem is the subsequent images are not following the same rule which is a totally strange behaviour because all I did was change the %age steps for other images as the animation pattern is absolutely same for all of them. But due some unknown reasons, other images are not following as expected and I don't see any logical reason. May be you could help me out!

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0n1zy1g1/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id='slideshow'>
    <figure id='imagestrip'>
        <img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="Photograph of a Black kite">
        <img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="Profile of a Red kite">
        <img src="images/img4.jpg" alt="Pelicans on moorings at sea">
        <img src="images/img9.jpg" alt="Photograph of Pariah kite">
    </figure>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slideshow {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 20em;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    perspective: 850px;
/*  outline: 3px solid blue;*/
}
#slideshow figure {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: slider2 30s infinite;
    outline: 2px solid red;
}
figure img {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    outline: 3px solid yellow;
}
@keyframes slider2 {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateZ(0px); /*Zoom-in*/
    }
    2% {
/*      transform: translateX(-25%);*/
        transform: translateZ(250px);
    }
    20% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateZ(250px);
    }
    22% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateZ(0px);
    }
    25% {
        /*transform: translateX(-25%);*/
        transform: translateZ(0);
        transform: translateX(-25%);
    }
    27% {
        /*transform: translateX(-25%);*/
        transform: translateZ(250px);
        transform: translateX(-25%);
    }
    45% {
        transform: translateZ(250px);
        transform: translateX(-25%);
    }
    47% {
        transform: translateZ(0px);
        transform: translateX(-25%);
    }
    50% {
        /*transform: translateZ(100px);*/
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        /*transform: translateZ(0px);*/
    }
    57% {
        transform: translateZ(250px);
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    75% {
        transform: translateZ(250px);
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    77% {
        transform: translateZ(0px);
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    80% {
        /*transform: translateZ(250px);*/
        transform: translateX(-75%);
    }
```

My pattern is as follows:

An image Zooms-in for, say, 1s and stays for a while, say, 5s and then zooms-out again for 1s. then it slides left by `transform: translateX(%)`. This pattern is successful for first image but as the second image slides in, nothing happens, though the animation rules are same for other images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to specify multiple transforms to an element, they should be set to the same property as space separated values and not add a second `transform` property with the next transform. If you do it that way, then the latest `transform` would override the one that was provided earlier within same keyframe.

For example, in the below keyframe only the `transform: translateZ(0px)` has a value.

```
0% {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateZ(0px); 
}
```

```css
  #slideshow {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 20em;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    perspective: 850px;
    /*    outline: 3px solid blue;*/
  }
  #slideshow figure {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    animation: slider2 30s infinite;
    outline: 2px solid red;
  }
  figure img {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    outline: 3px solid yellow;
  }
  @keyframes slider2 {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0%) translateZ(0px);
    }
    2% {
      transform: translateZ(250px);
    }
    20% {
      transform: translateX(0%) translateZ(250px);
    }
    22% {
      transform: translateX(0%) translateZ(0px);
    }
    25% {
      transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-25%);
    }
    27% {
      transform: translateZ(250px) translateX(-25%);
    }
    45% {
      transform: translateZ(250px) translateX(-25%);
    }
    47% {
      transform: translateZ(0px) translateX(-25%);
    }
    50% {
      transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    57% {
      transform: translateZ(250px) translateX(-50%);
    }
    75% {
      transform: translateZ(250px) translateX(-50%);
    }
    77% {
      transform: translateZ(0px) translateX(-50%);
    }
    80% {
      transform: translateX(-75%);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id='slideshow'>
  <figure id='imagestrip'>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/41/NmnKzKIyQsyGIkFjiNsb_20140717_212636-3.jpg?q=80&fm=jpg&s=ce9ba69c9caf7d6483d874466478bc9b" alt="Photograph of a Black kite">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/41/NmnKzKIyQsyGIkFjiNsb_20140717_212636-3.jpg?q=80&fm=jpg&s=ce9ba69c9caf7d6483d874466478bc9b" alt="Profile of a Red kite">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/41/NmnKzKIyQsyGIkFjiNsb_20140717_212636-3.jpg?q=80&fm=jpg&s=ce9ba69c9caf7d6483d874466478bc9b" alt="Pelicans on moorings at sea">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/41/NmnKzKIyQsyGIkFjiNsb_20140717_212636-3.jpg?q=80&fm=jpg&s=ce9ba69c9caf7d6483d874466478bc9b" alt="Photograph of Pariah kite">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: you rock man! I knew that I am not following the best practice but nobody does in learning phase, right! BTW thanks a 100! for correcting the code and thanks a gazillion for pin-pointing the reason.

Comment: @Lahori: Everybody starts at 0 and so that's normal. I've made mistakes like these several times too :)